# Obtain in array form or array a datasource on Wakanda

Tags: wakanda

I would like to know if it's possible to obtain in array form or array a datasource on Wakanda to process data more easily on JavaScript.

Comment: can you provide an example of a datasource data you find bothersome to process?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert any *entity* or *entityCollection* to array using the provided `toArray` method.

Example:

```
ds.Test.all().toArray();
```

[documentation page](http://livedoc.wakanda.org/Datasource/Server-Datasources/toArray.301-631727.en.html)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, thanks for the answer, i have already use this method but when i load my page, the page crash.

Server-side :

```
     exports.myDataArray = function arrayDom()
    {
    var myArray = ds.myTable.all().toArray();
    return myArray;
    }

    client-side 

    var myNewArray myModule.myDataArray();
    console.log(myNewArray);
```

=>>> CRASH

Or when i have chance i obtain in the console :

```
() function{
            var result = '',
            message = {},
            request = {},
            i = 0;
            request = new WAF.proxy.HttpRequest ({
                url         :…
```

or `console.log(myNewArray[10])` => UNDEFINED

Comment: You cannot call a server side module directly on the frontend. You need to expose it through REST or dataclass methods.
For example, `ds.myTable.all().convertToArray()` where `convertToArray` contains all `myDataArray` content.
Plus, there is mistake in your code: `var myNewArray = myModule.myDataArray();`